# how to add a user to mongo from Rails (console or rake)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'd like to do the equivalent of:

```
mongo --port 27xxx
use admin
db.addUser("venkman", "StayPuft!1")
```

But I'd like to do it as part of my `rake db:seed`. Seems like something you'd want to to with a fresh database. I thought that some variant of this:

```
Mongoid.database.eval('use admin; db.addUser("venkman", "StayPuft!1")' )
```

would do the trick, but I'm not having much luck with it:

```
Mongo::OperationFailure: Database command '$eval' failed: (errmsg: 
  'compile failed: JS Error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement nofile_a:0'; ok: '0.0').
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/db.rb:520:in `command'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/db.rb:407:in `eval'
```

I can get a function like this to work:

```
irb(main):023:0> Mongoid.database.eval(' function() { return 3+3; }' )
=> 6.0
```

So it seems that `database.eval` is not the right thing to use for scripting db admin tasks. Reasonably sure this issue isn't related to mongoid, from the stack trace. Is there something that I can use to script a user create as part of my `rake db:seed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eval fails because the javascript code is executed in the context of the database server, not the client shell. I am not totally sure, but I don't think you can do what you want with Mongoid alone.

However, if you use the Ruby driver, the code will look like this:

```
# set host and port with appropriate values
admindb = Mongo::Connection.new(host, port)['admin']
admindb.add_user("venkman", "StayPuft!1")
```

Having said that, I would not recommend putting hard coded passwords in your code were everybody can see it...

Comment: well this would only be in the seed code, that seems reasonably safe, no?

Comment: I just wanted to say that you have to be careful. It should be fine if you know what you are doing.